# How to disable scroll on HTML5 date inputs having a webshim fallback in

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html-input, webshim

I'm trying without success to disable scroll on an HTML5 date input.
This input has a webshim fallback, which cause my JS to works with Chrome, but not Firefox.

```js
$('.input-date input').on('mousewheel', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.15.6/dev/polyfiller.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
  webshim.setOptions({
    'forms-ext': {
      widgets: {
        calculateWidth: false
      }
    }
  });
  webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>

<form>
  <div class="input-date">
    <input type="date" value="2015-02-24">
  </div>
</form>
```

Does anyone ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the opportunity to discuss of this problem with webshim's author, and it was found that an option is available to avoid this kind of problem: `noSpinbtn`.

Thus, the code will looks like this:

```js
$('.input-date input').on('mousewheel', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.15.6/dev/polyfiller.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  webshims.cfg.no$Switch = true;
  webshim.setOptions({
    'forms-ext': {
      widgets: {
        calculateWidth: false
      },
      date: {
        noSpinbtn: true
      }
    }
  });
  webshim.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>

<form>
  <div class="input-date">
    <input type="date" value="2015-02-24">
  </div>
</form>
```